# ASP.net 5 publish output too large?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, publish

I have a barebones ASP.net 5 web project, created from the Empty template.

I publish it in the file system. I have the folders /approot, /logs, and /wwwroot in /bin/WebsiteName/Release/PublishOutput.

The /approot folder alone is 103MB.

That seems a bit much. How to lower that?

If that is how it is, what new concepts may I might not know?

Answer (score 0):

That folder has the application, its dependencies, and the runtime. Basically, everything that you need in order to run the app. Move it to another machine and it runs, nothing else needed. If the app runs on CoreCLR, there's a good chance that a big chunk of that folder is only the runtime.

Now, there are a few ways to reduce the size of the deployment package but then you'll have to get the dependencies and/or the runtime on the target server.

So, a full application, with everything would be published with `dnu` like this:

```
dnu publish --runtime <runtime1> ... --runtime <runtimeN> --no-source`
```

1. Publish only for a particular framework. If your app targets both `dnxcore50` (CoreCLR) and `dnx451` (Desktop CLR) you can chose to publish only one of them using `dnu publish`:

   `dnu publish --framework dnxcore50 --runtime <the framework for dnxcore50>`
2. Don't publish the runtime. Leave the runtime out and get it somehow else on the target machine (that's what Azure WebSites does):

   `dnu publish` (no `--runtime`)
3. I don't recommend this but if you really want you can compile the target app on the server and only publish the sources. Then you can restore (`dnu restore`) on the server.
4. Check if you really need all the packages that your app includes. For example, do you include `System.Linq.Expressions` but don't use it? It will be published because the publish algorithm cannot determine what's actually used.

Comment: I'm publishing only dnxcore50. I'm fine with needing to upload the runtime (88 megs worth of the package) once, if multiple websites can access reference it, So, once it's up on the target server, how do I reference that from a project?

Comment: Make sure `dnx` is on the `PATH` and the the `DNX_HOME` variable is set

Comment: On point 4 - how do you control this? Dependencies such as System.Linq.Expressions are automatically included when I include higher-level dependencies in my project.json. Do we just manually delete folders in approot/packages/?